# How Do I Read A JSON File Path And Ignore Certain Characters?

Tags: java, file-io

How do I read a JSON file path and ignore the timestamp or any other characters in the file name? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

**Goal:**

Read a JSON file starting with ex: `Example Data Document` and ignore the rest of the time stamp.

**Current workflow:**

The file path has a common name that it always starts with (ex:`Example Data Document`.)

At the end of the common name, is usually a time stamp. (*I download this file repeatedly on  a daily basis in my web automation and the file name always has an updated timestamp in the file name*)

How I'm currently reading the file path:

```
Boolean filePath = JsonPath.from(new File("/User/myName/Desktop/Example Data Document-768-8_23_2022\,\ 4_5102\ PM.json"))
```

Research I've done:

Looked into Filters and Query but nothing in here seems to indicate what I need.

[https://support.smartbear.com/](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html)

**EDIT:**
ANSWERED BY:

@tgdavies in comment section of this post.

**Resource:** [listFiles Java method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-listfiles-method-in-java-with-examples/)

I am able to read from a directory using the `fileList` method and filter through only the needed file path name by getting the pre-fix('Example Data Document') and suffix ('.json') and ignoring any other characters.

```
    import java.io.*;
  
public class solution {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
  
        // try-catch block to handle exceptions
        try {
  
            // Create a file object
            File f = new File("/Users/yourUser/Downloads");
  
            // Create a FilenameFilter
            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
  
                public boolean accept(File f, String name)
                {
                    return name.startsWith("Example Data Document");
                }
            };
  
            // Get all the names of the files present
            // in the given directory
            // and whose names start with "Example Data Document"
            File[] files = f.listFiles(filter);

            // Display the names of the files
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(files[i].getName());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at `File.listFiles`. It's not clear what your question has to do with JSON?

Comment: I've edited the tags.  This question is about file I/O, not JSON or JSON Path.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you, and you're right, this should have anything to do with reading specifically a JSON file, rather reading a file path using Java methods. I'm still looking into the `listFiles` method at the moment to see how I can achieve this.

Comment: @tgdavies I am able to get what I need from your suggestion. The `listFiles` method was the way to go. Thank you very much.